# Unnecessary character is coming in php webservice response(JSON)

Tags: android

I am parsing one web-service which contains all the countries name listing in the list.But some of the countries in the list contains some unwanted characters which is shown in lollipop.Now i want to remove that characters when fetching the response.How can i remove this?This character you ca[image]n show in the image.

Comment: Can you show the JSON data?

Comment: 37:  {
id: "38"
name: "Comoros"
code: "+269"
ISO code: "KM"
}-
38:  {
id: "39"
name: "Congo, (Congo  Kinshasa)"
code: "+243"
ISO code: "CD"
}-
39:  {
id: "40"
name: "Congo, (Congo  Brazzaville)"
code: "+242"
ISO code: "CG"
}-
40:  {
id: "41"
name: "Costa Rica"
code: "+506"
ISO code: "CR"
}-
41:  {
id: "42"
name: "Cote d'Ivoire (Ivory Coast)"
code: "+225"
ISO code: "CI"
}-
42:  {
id: "43"
name: "Croatia"
code: "+385"
ISO code: "HR"
}-
43:  {
id: "44"
name: "Cuba"
code: "+53"
ISO code: "CU"
}